# Can't mass-assign protected attributes HABTM Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I try create a HBTM association and create the record when i create my order like this:

order controller:

```
  def create
    @order = Order.create(params[:order])

    @order.adresses.new(:order_id => params[:id],:adress_id => params[:adress_id])
    if @order.save
      redirect_to orders_path,:notice => "Compra criada com sucesso !"
    else
      redirect_to orders_path,:notice => "Compra nao criada com sucesso cheque os erros e tente novamente !"
    end
  end
```

in my order model and my adress model:

```
order.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :adresses
adress.rb
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
```

right but i create a model and receive this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: adress_id, order_id
```

so i create the model adresses_orders.rb whit this:

```
  attr_accessible :order_id,:adress_id
```

but the error continuous i dont understood because what

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: adress_id, order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `attr_accessible :order_id,:adress_id` In adress.rb NOT in adresses_orders.rb

And no need to define adress_orders.rb, if possible delete it

Answer (score 0):

HABTM do not need an extra model in between (adresses_orders). Just the table is enough.

```
@order.address.new
```

should be enough. Association is clever enough to fill in the address id and order id for you.